# how to slide a list on clicking next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a list attribute for listing thumbnail images of youtube generated playlist(gdata feed).But I want it to wrap the list inside a div container then I want to have next and previous buttons to slide the playlist images.

Any one please help with some idea..

Comment: you can use jquery carousel for image sliding..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow shyamsundar055! Although you did describe your problem, it is difficult to help you without knowing what your code looks like. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with a jquery plugin like this one http://als.musings.it/. After implementing the js library, style sheets, and HTML provided in this link you can place the thumbnails and other content you desire between the list tags. You can find other plugins by performing the google search, "jquery sliding list plugin."

Comment: Leaving an answer with only a link and no description is not going to be useful to the user. If the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. It is also just giving the user another hoop to jump through to find their answer. So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.

Comment: I edited my answer, now I'd appreciate it if you edited your vote.

Answer (score -2):

For sliding your image thumbnail why not you try the j query lite plugin it is easy to instal. [jquerylight box](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Comment: Leaving an answer with only a link and no description is not going to be useful to the user. If the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. It is also just giving the user another hoop to jump through to find their answer So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.